# mCrypt extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I'm trying to setup my Opencart site, and I have the local site working on my Debian development machine, for production I have a Centos 5.4 VPS with apache and stuff. When I try to install OpenCart in the VPS, on step 2 it says:

```
Warning: mCrypt extension needs to be loaded for OpenCart to work!
```

Also shows extensions such as mysql, GD, cURL and mCrypt set to off and when they should be set to on.

The version of mCrypt is

```
Mcrypt v2.6.8 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Enlazado contra libmcrypt v2.5.8
```

PHP -V

```
PHP 5.3.28 (cli) (built: Dec 18 2013 20:31:55) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

PHP -m

```
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
exif
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
memcache
mysql
mysqli
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
snmp
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
zip
zlib
```

and apache version:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.3
Server built:   Oct 16 2013 12:18:29
```

As you can see, everything seems to on it's place, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same issue and its fixed by below commands,

```
mv -i /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/

sudo php5enmod mcrypt

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue on ubuntu 14.04 with php fpm and nginx

```
apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

Create symlink to mods-avaliable

```
ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
```

if you get this message then just ignore it. it will worl

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini’: File exists
```

Enable It.

```
php5enmod mcrypt
```

Restart php-fpm

```
service php5-fpm restart
```

Restart nginx

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: Yes, for some reason is less complicated to do this stuff in the .deb world...